# What's the difference between читать and прочесть?

Tags: выбор-слова, глаголы, вид

Both seem to mean "to read", so what's the diff?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Verbs have different aspect (see other questions on this forum about aspect, [this one](https://russian.stackexchange.com/q/114) in particular).
*читать* is an imperfect verb, it denotes a process in its development, an unfinished activity.
*прочесть* is a perfect verb, it denotes a completed activity.

Examples:

> Я читаю книгу. (читать)
> I am reading a book.
>
> Я прочел книгу. (прочесть)
> I've read the book (till the end).
>
> Когда ты будешь читать книгу, которую я тебе подарил на день рождения? (читать)
> When will you read the book I gave you for your birthday?
>
> Когда ты прочтешь книгу, которую я тебе подарил на день рождения? (прочесть) 
> When will you finish reading the book I gave you for your birthday?

Comment: It should be "I've read a book", not "red a book". Stupid minimum edit length restriction.

Comment: I have to spell check what I'm writing! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

*Прочесть* is the same (but older) as *прочитать*, which is just a perfective aspect of *читать*. So, *читать* means 'to read', *прочитать* means 'to have read'.

Comment: The two are not interchangeable in the meaning of "being busy reading". *Я прочитал всю дорогу* is correct, *я прочёл всю дорогу* is not.

Comment: @Quassnoi I believe, it is actually two different verbs *прочитать*, one meaning "to spend some time interval reading" and another one meaning "to finish reading".